# Sorting a List using Delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a class called person, with a string called name, and an int called wins. I then have a list of people called "PS4". I want to order the ps4 list by the people with the most wins.

this doesn't seem to work.

```
PS4.Sort(delegate(Person c1, Person c2) { return c1.Wins.CompareTo(c2.Wins); });
```

is the delegate right? or do I need to use an orderby or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It is right, and you can simplify it with lambda statements:

```
PS4.Sort( (c1,c2) => c1.Wins.CompareTo(c2.Wins) );
```

Comment: hmm, it didnt seem to order it for me.

Comment: why ? did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
PS4 = PS4.OrderBy(z=> z.wins).ToList();
```

Comment: Note, that this creates a another, second List object. List.Sort() avoids creation of another List object and is therefore preferable.

Comment: The relevance of your answer being applicable depends on the particular application code. You assign a new list to the PS4 **variable**. The original list object (which could be referenced somewhere else in the code) is not being sorted.

Comment: I worked a complete solution with this logic and I never faced the case you're talking about. Anyway, I know it's not the best way performance-wise.

Comment: What you say is wrong. Your code snippet **does not** sort the list object referenced by the variable PS4. It rather assigns a reference to **another** list object to the variable PS4. It is not that hard to understand, isn't it? Whether it is relevant for you doesn't matter. It is only relevant how the answer fits to the question.